# Error Exporting Vuforia Unity Project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm using the **Unity's Vuforia Extension**, and created a AR scene. But while exporting to Android, a pop up came and SDK outdated, but my SDK is the latest.
I clicked continue and imported the project into Eclipse.
But while trying to run the project, it doesn't launch saying the projects have errors. 
I tried cleaning and running again, it shows me this in the Console tab:

```
[2015-02-14 10:06:34 - QCARPlayerNativeActivity] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2015-02-14 10:06:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/qualcomm/QCARUnityPlayer/BuildConfig;
[2015-02-14 10:06:34 - QCARPlayerNativeActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/qualcomm/QCARUnityPlayer/BuildConfig;
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the export window, I didn't click select the scene before clicking export.

Problem solved.